# Any free (no fee) beaches in Cape May?

Tags: beaches, new-jersey

Are there any free (no fee) beach areas in [Cape May](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_May,_New_Jersey), where you don't need a [beach tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beach_tag)?

Comment: "Free beach" has multiple meanings. And the term "beach tag" is unfamiliar to some of us. Could you expand the question a bit please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it turns out that [Cape May has a beach guide online](http://www.capemaycountychamber.com/visitor/beach-guide.htm).

It lists details of 14 beaches in the area.

Each entry begins with "Beach Fees". The following beaches are free, as in you don't need a beach tag:

- North Wildwood Beach
- Sea Isle City Beach (Wednesdays only)
- Upper Township Beach
- Wildwood Beach
- Wildwood Crest Beach

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer's link is no longer active.
Here is an updated answer for 2018.

The following town's beaches are free:

- North Wildwood
- Sea Isle City (Wednesdays only)
- The beach in the Strathmere section of Upper Township
- Somers Point - William Morrow Beach (a bayfront beach)
- Wildwood
- Wildwood Crest
- Atlantic City (38 miles north of Cape May)

All other oceanfront beaches in Cape May and Atlantic Counties charge a fee during the summer season.

Comment: My guy feeling is it would be better to edit the existing answer rather than propose a new one.  But I could be wrong about this.

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be basically the same list as the previous answer, with the addition of Atlantic City (which is not all that close to Cape May).

Comment: What does the linked website add to the answer?

Comment: @JoErNanO the website link was an updated and active link to the answer by hippietrail who's website link does not work. Why would you delete an active link on my answer but leave the deadlink on the other answer?

Comment: If that is the case then you should update dead links on other answers as opposed to posting your own.

Comment: I was unaware that a user was allowed to add additional information to another users answer. I thought we could only edit spelling errors, grammar, spelling etc. If I simply just changed the link, that would be understandable. Can I get confirmation from a Mod, that a user can "improve" another users answer by adding additional information to their answer.

Comment: @AirportChariotCarandLimo You most definitely can (and should) update existing answers when you notice dead links.